# Reloading module's services.yml

Tags: 8

I am trying to reload the .services.yml file of a custom module without having to reinstall the module.

Is there a Drush command or another way to achieve this?
Does `drush cr` also clear the services.yml files information? It's really hard for me to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After testing and more research "drush cr" does the job. Service.yml is reloaded after clearing the cache.